# Why do the Preboot mixins no longer compile after Less 1.3.1?

Tags: css, less

I am using Codekit to compile less files and ever since it jumped to Less 1.3.1 (back around October '12) it will no longer compile past my Preboot (http://www.markdotto.com/bootstrap) mixins.

It doesn't look like Preboot is maintained anymore and the github link goes to a 404.

Does anything in the mixin code jump out as being the issue with whatever change Less did?

Is their anything similiar to Preboot that maybe is more actively maintained?

Comment: The author of preboot.less (Mark Otto) has change his username in GitHub, so the source are now at: https://github.com/mdo/Preboot.less

Comment: any error when compiling?